# when extending base.html: Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, html, django

My page loads only if I don't extend base.html.

When I add the tags:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<p>hi</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the error mentioned in the title.

Here's my file structure:

```
parent_folder/
   /env
   /app
     views.py
     urls.py
     models.py
     manage.py
     settings.py
     db.sqlite3
     /template
        base.html
        about.html 
   /static
     css/
       styles.css
     javascript/
       base.js
```

In **settings.py**, static url:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

It explicitly says

```
Error during template rendering:  in template .... error at line 0
```

in base.html

I'm pretty new to Django - this is my second app.  Can someone give me an idea of what's going on here?  I've removed all of my imports, and it's still not workign. Here's my current **base.html**:

```html
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="headercontainer">
      <span id="header">Header</span>
      <div id="container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
      <ul id="nav">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href={% url "logout" %}>Logout</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Edit Your Profile</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href={% url '' %}></a>
          </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href={% url 'campers' %}>Header</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href={% url '' %}>header</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">header</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href={% url '' %}>link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">link</a>
            </ul>
            </li>
            {%else %}
            <li><a href="/login/">header</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href={% url '' %}>header</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              {% endif %}
              <li><a href="#">header</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href={% url 'prep' %}>link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <ul>
              </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's in your ```views.py```?

Comment: def about(request):
    return render_to_response('about.html', RequestContext(request))

Comment: Do I need a view for base.html? I didn't use one in my last app.

Comment: `{% url '' %}` may be the problem.  It's trying to look up a nonexistent URL name.

Comment: Yeah, you should provide url name in {% url '' %}

Answer (score 3):

You cannot leave url templatetags with empty strings, because the template tag `{% url %}` is search urls in your urls.py for any possible matches, but in your case it might have nothing to match, hence the error.

Comment: Ah! That did it! I thought I could just leave empty values, and no.  Learning, learning learning.  Thank you much.